# Bind MenuItem.Visibility to TabItem.IsSelected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What I'm trying to do here is set the visibility of a MenuItem based on whether a certain tab is selected on a TabControl, the 'View' menu in this case.  My preference would be to avoid doing this in code-behind, which I'm sure must be possible.

I'll Post what I've got, but it's obviously wrong.

```
<Window x:Class="CallEntryTool.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Call Entry" Height="720" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu Height="27" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" >
                <MenuItem Header="_Open Customer File" />
                <MenuItem Header="E_xit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View"
                      Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                      >
                <MenuItem Header="_Refresh">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Incremental" />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Full" />
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StatusBarItem Content="Customer File.bpcl"></StatusBarItem>
            <Separator/>
            <StatusBarItem Content="Server Status"></StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <TabControl x:Name="_mainTabControl">
            <TabItem x:Name="_callEntryTab" Header="Customer Call Entry">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="_geoDisplayTab" Header="Geographic Display">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="_callsTab" Header="Customer Calls">
                <Grid x:Name="_customerCallsTab" Background="#FFE5E5E5" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="_unassocCallsTab" Header="Unassociated Calls">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The first obvious problem is I'm trying to bind the 'View' menu item to the 'IsSelected' property of a TabItem, but I don't know how to specify which TabItem.

The second problem is that the TabControl is not an ancestor of the MenuItem, so the FindAncestor call won't work.

A lot of the on-line articles that solve similar (but not the same) problems change the DataContext of the containers.  This will be an MVVM app, so the DataContext will be my view-model, right?

Apologies for what is probably something that I should have been able to figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be tired.  Here's the solution.

```
<MenuItem Header="_View"
            Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=_callsTab}"
            >
```

Time for a nap...